# jQuery File Upload MySQL integration into existing Table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to implement the jQuery File Upload plugin into my website. I can get the images to go to the directory that I want it to and I can get the filename, as well.

The problem I am having is that is that I would like to get the name of the files, along with the name of the album (which I'll provide) and store them into a table. Conversely, if an image is deleted, that particular row is deleted, along with it.

I have tried following this [link](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration) to help me, but it doesn't help that there is no explanation, either in code or in the documentation as to what these pieces of code actually do or how they work.

I hav no idea what *Client-side file upload initialization*, *Client side upload template additions* or *Client side download template additions* do or how they relate to me in any way. I do not want to implement a form. I just want to use existing data (e.g. filename from UploadHandler.php) and put it into a MySQL table.

Could someone please explain to me how *Extension of `index.php` for the database integration* connects together? I've seen other posts on how frustrating it is to try and understand the integration process.